# unable to insert form datas into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I need to insert all form details into database and save the uploaded image in a location. I succeeded in uploading the file to specified location. But form details are not getting inserted into database.

This is the code in `pages.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['uname']) && !empty($_SESSION['pswd'])) {
    include 'classes/insert.php';
    $db_con->dbcon();
    $db_con->insert_data();
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['bg_img']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bg_img']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['bg_img']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>New Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Add pages</p>
        <a href="logout.php">logout</a>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
        <br /><br />
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Page name</label>
            <input type="text" name="page_name" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label>Page title</label>
            <input type="text" name="page_title" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label>Page bg img</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
            <input type="file" name="bg_img" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label>Page content</label>
            <textarea name="page_content"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php } else {
    $home_loc = 'index.php';
    header ('Location:' .$home_loc);}
?>
```

This is the code in `insert.php`

```
class db_con {
    public function dbcon() {
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $pswd     = 'admin';
        $dbname   = 'web';
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $pswd) or die('cudn\'t connect');
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('cudn\'t select db');
    }

    function insert_data() {
        $this->dbcon();
        if (isset($_POST['page_name']) && isset($_POST['page_title']) && isset($_POST['bg_img']) && isset($_POST['page_content'])) {
            $pg_name      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page_name']);
            $pg_title     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page_title']);
            $pg_img       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bg_img']);
            $pg_content   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page_content']);
            $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages (page_name, page_title, page_bg_img, page_content) VALUES ('" . $pg_name . "', '" . $pg_title . "', '" . $pg_img . "', '" . $pg_content . "')");
        }
    }
}

$db_con = new db_con();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have brackets around your instanciation of the classes? `$insert = new insert();`

Comment: what is the error accrued ?

Comment: I added brackets to instances but it doesn't make any changes. No error is displayed. But if I remove 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' the datas are getting inserted.

Comment: are you mixing javascript `var` with PHP ?

Comment: action=""enctype="multipart/form-data" should have space like action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: I've added the insert query inside the function "insert_data()" inside the class named "insert". Isn’t that what you are asking for?

Comment: Actually doing after some research I found that before declaring a variable inside a class we must add "var" keyword before the variable name, that is why I added it. And if I remove that it shows an error. Sorry I've added the space but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, there are many things to consider.

- You are mixing Javascript with PHP.

  change this

  ```
      var $hostname = 'myhostname';
  ```

to

```
      $hostname = 'myhostname';
```

same with others.

- you shouldnt make many classes in your case.

use this:

```
  class db_con{
       public function dbcon(){
          ......... 
         }
       function insert_data() {
           ...........
         }
     }
```

- you are not calling the `insert_data()` function

call it like that:

```
   $insert = new insert; 
   $insert->insert_data();
```

- you should escape your variables, like that:

  ```
        $pg_title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page_title']);
  ```
- you should switch to `PDO` or `MYSQLI`.

EDIT:

try this

```
    session_start();
   if(!empty($_SESSION['uname']) && !empty($_SESSION['pswd'])){
    include 'classes/insert.php';
   $db_con = new db_con();
   $db_con->dbcon();
   $db_con->insert_data();
```

EDIT2:

To get the uploaded file use `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST`:

```
    $pg_img       = $_FILES['bg_img'];
```

change this also

```
  and $_FILES['bg_img']['name'] != ''
```

instead of

```
  && isset($_POST['bg_img'])
```

Comment: I've changed as u said. But no change. I've updated the code above. Kindly check it.

Comment: where are you calling this `insert_data()` ?

Comment: I'm calling the "insert_data()" & "dbcon()" functions in "pages.php" below the "include" statement.

Comment: i used your code, but no change. should I delete the "$db_con = new db_con();" from "insert.php"? And FYI if I remove "enctype="multipart/form-data"" from form, datas are getting inserted into database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works. Now I receive a warning, stating that " mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given". And in database that column is empty. Can you tell me on how to manipulate this "$pg_img = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['bg_img']);"?

Comment: you escaped the image ? no , look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861967/php-mysql-file-contents-escape-problem) how to handel with image  , ok glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have successfully connected to the database, If not, change your initialization from `$db_con = new db_con;` to `$db_con = new db_con();`

EDITED:
I think you should also need to change your process flow. Separate the form, the insertion process and the database connection. I suggest you create 3 separate files:
1. The Form page (HTML)
2. The process page (PHP file where you will link your form. Or where the processes will be happening)
3. The Database connection file (PHP file. Put your db connection here and other db-related functionalities).

Here's my example:

Form Page:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>New Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Add pages</p>
        <a href="logout.php">logout</a>
        <br /><br />
        <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
        <br /><br />
        <form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Page name</label>
            <input type="text" name="page_name" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label>Page title</label>
            <input type="text" name="page_title" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label>Page bg img</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
            <input type="file" name="bg_img" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label>Page content</label>
            <textarea name="page_content"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can seee, I pointed the action of the form to process.php.

Here's my sample process.php:

```
<?php
include 'classes/db.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   // get your post data here
   $post_data = array('your post data');
   // instantiate db
   $db = new Db();
   // create db connection
   $db_connect = $db->connect();
   // check if successfully connected to db
   // then call the insertion process
   $db->insert_data('table_name', $post_data);
}
```

Then in your db.php file:

```
<?php 
 class Db {

     function connect(){
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $pwd      = 'admin';
        $dbname   = 'yourdbname';
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $pswd) or die('couldn\'t connect');
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('couldn\'t select db');
     }

     function insert_data($table_name, $data) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (page_name, page_title, page_bg_img, page_content) VALUES ($data);
     }

 }
?>
```

Just don't follow my insertion process coz I just made it short. Its just the flow I wanted to show.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've edited as u said. I'm able to connect to database.

Comment: I think you should also need to change your process flow. Separate the form, the insertion process and the database connection. I suggest you create 3 separate files:
1. The Form page (HTML)
2. The process page (PHP file where you will link your form. Or where the processes will be happening)
3. The Database connection file (PHP file. Put your db connection here and other db-related functionalities).